# Equivalent of ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus

I have some code that I would like to migrate from [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) to [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus), considering the former package is considered deprecated.

One of the things I cannot figure out how to do with this new package, is to build/manipulate connection strings. Specifically, I was using [ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.servicebusconnectionstringbuilder?view=azure-dotnet) to parse the connection strings from my configuration and get the `EntityPath`, as well as a few other things provided by this class.

Am I overlooking something, or was this functionality completely removed?

Comment: Did you [check Fuget](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/7.4.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.dll/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/ServiceBusConnectionStringProperties)? That tells you the types in an assembly, and it might be easy to find where it moved to. ServiceBusConnectionStringProperties looks promising.

Comment: @mason I saw that type, but completely overlooked the `Parse` static method to initialize it, replacing the constructor of `ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder`. Lack of coffee today, I suppose 
Unfortunately, not all the functionality has been ported over to this new class.

Comment: Feel free to turn that into an answer! I'm sure other devs would benefit from the info. My team hasn't yet made the jump to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, but it's on our to-do list.

Comment: The only method that turns that class into a connection string is an internal method. So it looks like there simply is no equivalent connection string builder. Very sad. Hard to call this a replacement library if it cannot replace existing code in the old library.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that Microsoft renamed the `ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder`
into a poorly named and inferior [ServiceBusConnectionStringProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusconnectionstringproperties?view=azure-dotnet)

Which does expose a static method `ServiceBusConnectionStringProperties Parse(string)`.

This will, however, not provide all the connectionstring metadata as the builder was.

Comment: I don't get it why this answer had a -1, but I upvoted it to 0. But this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse easily yourself:

```
        IDictionary<string, string> ParseConnectionString(string connectionString)
        {
            var result = connectionString.Split(';').Select(x =>
            {
                var items = x.Split('=', 2);
                return new { Key = items[0], Value = items[1] };
            }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

            return result;
        }
```